# I cannot change the text color to a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-table

I working on the following code and I have created a table that is suppose to have some links in there and the links on default come out to be white and I wanted to be black. I try changing the color to black but nothing happens. I am not sure if it has to do with the rest of the code above it or not. I would appreciate if someone can help me here.

http://class.ics.uci.edu/~191grp04/Evelina124/docs/sitemap.html

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 4):

You have this in your CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none; /* remove underline for link */
    color:#fff; /* default color is blue */
}
```

This sets the color to white. If you want it black, change `color: #fff;` to `color: #000;`.

If you only want the links in the table black, you could do it like this:

```
table a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your links are white because you styled them that way:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
```

Change the color to `color: #000`

Answer (score 0):

in your file, change this CSS line to whatever color you want:

```
a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```